# How to make the hostname of VM resolvable when Cisco VPN is connected?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, vpn, hostname

In my Windows 10 computer, I have a VirtualBox Ubuntu 16.04 LTS VM in bridge adapter network setting. I have been able to use the hostname of the VM to SSH, Samba, and browse webpages inside the VM.

Also, the Windows 10 computer has Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client installed, so that I can remotely access my company's LAN. Like, remote desktop into the office computer, accessing file server, etc.

Recently, the IT department has told us to update the VPN client. After that, I have found the computer unable to resolve the hostname of the VM when the VPN is connected. When the VPN is disconnected, the hostname can be resolved again.

The updated version of the Cisco client is Version 4.2.03013. I do not know the version number before the update.

What should I do to make the hostname stays resolvable when the VPN is connected?

Comment: Did any settings change during the VPN client update? E.g. did split routing get turned off?

Comment: @Hennes There is no change on the user side, i.e. my side. Whether there are admin side changes, I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Add the IP address and the hostname into your local hosts-file may solve the problem. Under Windows 10, the file is protected from accidential editing so you must start notepad.exe in Administrator Mode to be able to overwrite the file.